# Como eliminar las lineas de advertencia en vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

quisiera apoyo, al momento de abrir Visual Code me muestra lineas de advertencias, he investigado y he desinstalado Eslint sin embargo eso no ha resuelto el problema, quise volver al instalar vuetify y me arrojó el siguiente error, yo no he eliminado nada externo que tenga que ver con el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor en lo posible trata de no agregar imágenes y mas bien agrega el error. Ademas el error que te muestra es una advertencia super grande pues te esta diciendo que te eliminar el `package.json` de tu proyecto, verifica que esta pasando.

Comment: Exacto, ahorita ya no me marca ese error con el package.json sin embargo las líneas amarillas no se quitan

Comment: Agrega las lineas amarillas que te muestra.